# which is the best approach to perform for loop?

Tags: python, list, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists and inside every list, I have to check if the second element is "**daemon**", so I wrote a code to that like this:

```py
### code 1
def chech_for_count(my_list: list):
    counter_of = 0
    for item in my_list:
       if item[1].lower() == "daemon":
            counter_of += 1
    return counter_of
```

and the task was achieved well but came to my mind I could also make that done using *list comprehension* which I think it's more pythonic.

```py
### code 2
def chech_for_count(my_list: list):
    return len([item for item in my_list if item[1].lower() == "daemon"])
```

also, the code did what must be done successfully, my question is which one uses less memory and time?

I did a little test with `time.time()` and the results varied from one test to another like below:

```
| Test number|Using list comprehension|Using normal for-loop  |
|------------|------------------------|-----------------------|
| First      | 0.2046670913696289     | 0.18691778182983398   |
| Second     | 0.11920547485351562    | 0.20410394668579102   |
| Third      | 0.09914922714233398    | 0.1051473617553711    |
| Forth      | 0.10482406616210938    | 0.1894378662109375    |
| Sum        | 0.52784585952758788    | 0.6856069564819336    |
```

The reason behind my question because I doubt if these numbers are real because I think some tests were slower because of CPU usage or something related to the hardware if not, based on these results can we say list comprehension has a better performance?

Comment: " I could also make that done using list comprehension which I think it's more pythonic" - Well, no. List comprehensions are meant to *build a list*. You don't want a list, just a count. Building a list to do that can only be inefficient, and is an abuse of the intent of the comprehension.

Comment: Given the high variances of your results, you cannot conclude about which is the fastest.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't try to time code using the wall time, see the `timeit` module.

Comment: Rather than creating a list, you can `sum` boolean values (0 or 1).

Comment: Can you post the code as an answer @YvesDaoust ?

Comment: No, I have not coded  that.

Comment: I don't think I understood what are you suggesting that's why I asked for a coded answer  @YvesDaoust

Comment: Using `sum` is not significantly faster. The main problem lies in `item[1].lower` which creates new strings but AFAIK there is no way in CPython not to create a new string in that case. Another big part of the overhead is the generator in CPython but in fact the main issue is CPython itself. Is this a real problem? How big are your lists?

Comment: the list can take up to 10k items (lists)

Comment: 10k is not a lot, but if speed is critical, you can try just to use Cython which should remove a significant part of the CPython overhead. If this is not enough and you use ASCII strings, then you could try to use C functions like `stricmp` from Cython (that does not require any string allocations and should be much faster). Alternatively, you could try to use PyPy if such problem is usual for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments you can use `sum()`:

```py
my_list = [[1, "xxx"], [2, "deamon"], [3, "deamon"]]

print(sum(l[1] == "deamon" for l in my_list))
```

Prints:

```
2
```

---

EDIT: Case-insensitive version:

```py
my_list = [[1, "xxx"], [2, "DEAMON"], [3, "deamon"]]

print(sum(l[1].lower() == "deamon" for l in my_list))
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Comment: This does not work with `"DEAMON"`: the case is not ignored as in the OP question

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yeah, I added `str.lower()` version.